# What is the index of $\mathbb{Z} \times2\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

As far as I know

$$\mathbb{Z}\times2\mathbb{Z}=\{(m,2n);m, n\in\mathbb{Z} \}, \ \ \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}=\{(p,q);p, q\in\mathbb{Z} \}. $$

In order to computer the cosets, do I have to consider the sum

$$(m+p, 2n+q)$$

And analise the cases where $m, n, p, q$ are odd and/or even? For example, if all of them are even, then

$$(p, q) +\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}=\{(\overline{0},\overline{0})\}, $$
since $m+p$ and $2n+q$ are even and, hence, they belong to $\overline {0} $.

Is this the way?

Comment: You need to form the quotient group (of the subgroup Zx2Z in the group ZxZ). The number of  elements of that quotient group is the desired index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, two elements $(u,v), (x,y) \in\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ are in the same coset iff $(u,v)-(x,y)\in \mathbb Z\times 2\mathbb Z$.

Let $(a,b) \in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$. There are two possibilites: $b$ is either even or odd.
If $b$ is even, then $(a,b)-(0,0)\in \mathbb Z\times 2\mathbb Z$.
If $b$ is odd,  then $(a,b)-(0,1)\in \mathbb Z\times 2\mathbb Z$, whence
there are two cosets: $(0,0)+\mathbb Z\times 2\mathbb Z$ and $(0,1)+\mathbb Z\times 2\mathbb Z$, i.e. the index is 2.

Comment: Can 0 and 1 be seen as the reminders of the divison by 2 or this does not make sense?

Comment: That is exactly the point!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$
Firstly, note that $\ZZ\times\ZZ$ is the bigger group. Using your notation, you want to count the number of cosets $$(p,q)+\ZZ\times2\ZZ$$ where $p,q\in\ZZ$. What happens to $(p,0)$? Well it goes to the coset $(0,0)+\ZZ\times2\ZZ$ because $p\in\ZZ$. What about $(p,2q')$ where $q'\in\ZZ$? This also is the identity in the quotient. And if the second entry was odd, then this corresponds to $(0,1)+\ZZ\times2\ZZ$. Since these are all the cases, then the index is 2.

In general, let $G,H,K,J$ be groups such that $H\leq G$ and $J\leq K$. The index is $$[G\times K:H\times J]=[G:H][K:J]$$ by the properties of the direct product.

Answer (score 1):

The index is $2$. The $2$ cosets are $\Bbb Z\oplus 2\Bbb Z$ and
$(0,1)+(\Bbb Z\oplus 2\Bbb Z)$.